# what is the purpose of filekey in parse server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Starting completely from scratch with a new server. Do we need to specify a filekey? If so, does it has to be something specific when I use AWS storage or not?

Answer (score 0):

In parse-server you dont have to put this keys

this is from parse-server wiki

> Parse Server does not require the use of client-side keys. This includes the client key, JavaScript key, .NET key, and REST API key.
>   The Application ID is sufficient to secure your app.
>
> However, you have the option to specify any of these four keys upon
>   initialization. Upon doing so, Parse Server will enforce that any
>   clients passing a key matches. The behavior is consistent with hosted
>   Parse.

The problem with this keys that they publish with you app and all of them (javascript key file key...) are not private. So their is no security  benefit to use them.